# Sending dynamically stamped pdf email attachments from postmarkapp

Tags: php, tcpdf, email-attachments, fpdf, postmark

I have a form template, i used fpdi and tcpdf to create a download link on the web application. 
http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/

What I now want is to be able to send out the same pdf once the users has click a button. I didn't save the form it's just a template and I stamped it with their order id then PDF sent with application/octet-stream.

I would like to use postmarkapp to do this. Does can anyone point me to the right direction.

A

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

At the end of that php script, you could simply send the file to the user in question with an API call to Postmark. Is that what you're trying to do? There is a good PHP library for Postmark here https://github.com/Znarkus/postmark-php If you integrate that in your php script, you should be able to just attach the generated pdf file to an API call and send it to the user who initiated the call to your site.